# Firestore recyclerview adapter generating out of bounds exception

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I have an activity with horizontal Firestore recyclerview and a textView, i want to set the textView with the 2nd event_name item from the recyclerview

```
nameSwitcher.setText(options.getSnapshots().get(1).getEvent_name());
```

the recycler view is working but the textView is generating `

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and code for getting the data from the database. Please also add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You list is empty. This check will keep your app from crash:

```
if (options.getSnapshots().size() >= 1) {
    nameSwitcher.setText(options.getSnapshots().get(1).getEvent_name());
}
```

Comment: it's not empty, in another method it's working ihave in the breakpoint `String evetName = options.getSnapshots().get(pos).getEvent_name(); option FirestoreRecyclerOptions@13220 pos: 3`
with `int pos = layoutManger.getActiveCardPosition();`

Comment: I can't see your full code, but exception clearly talks that you dont have 2 elents in you list.